# how to display streaming video on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, streaming

I am planning to write an iPhone app which can display streaming audio/video from the internet (backend would most probably be Red5 or Wowza and video will be streamed on RTMP (although I have the option to change that). Any ideas on implementation?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-UoLsSSw30 demos something similar to what I have in mind.

--
MI

Answer (score 0):

[You better know that](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/12/16/apple-requiring-the-http-live-stream-protocol-for-iphone-apps), and start looking at [HTTP Live Streaming](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-02)!

Displaying the video is as simple as having the `<video>` tag in an HTML5 page, but there should be an API also for that (I am not an iPhone developer)